# Automated DD Belated png script

Tags: javascript, png

I've been using http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/ for a while now and it has solved most of my IE6 png headaches.

I wonder though, whether there is a way of automating it so that I don't have litter my code with class="png" or adding the ids of html elements using background images to a JS file. - I don't care really that this would slow IE6 down - It's easier to explain to a client that the website is slow due to their browser than it is to explain why everything has a grey background!

I'm not really a JS expert but I guess grabbing the src attribute and adding the file name to the class isn't difficult. - Somehow parsing the CSS and and adding the id of the containing element sounds difficult if not impossible though??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't tested but here is my jQuery solution which should work. It basically checks all img elements for a .png extension then checks all elements except img for a background image with a .png extension

You may need to add in extra code to check for CSS background property as well as background-image. With the body * selector I would imagine a lot of overhead on pages with lots of elements but I'm with you, I don't care how long it takes IE6 users to load the page if they don't care about updating their browser

```
$(function() {
    $('img').each(function() {
            if(this.src.split('.').pop() == 'png') {
                    DD_belatedPNG.fixPng(this)
            }
    });
    $('body *:not(img)').each(function() {
            if($(this).css('background-image').split('.').pop().replace(/("|\')\)/,'') == 'png') {
                    DD_belatedPNG.fixPng(this);
            }
    });
});
```

EDIT: I found this quite an interesting challenge so wrote up a pure JavaScript solution. It needs to be run when the DOM is ready though, so if you really don't want to use jQuery or another framework with a DOM ready function you'll have to use Dean Edwards' method, like so:

```
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" id="domready" defer="defer" src="javascript:void(0)"><\/script>');
document.getElementById("domready").onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == "complete") {
        var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img')
        for(i=0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
            if(imgs[i].src.toLowerCase().search(/\.png$/) != -1) {
                DD_belatedPNG.fixPng(imgs[i]);
            }
        }

        var children = document.body.getElementsByTagName('*');
        for(i=0; i < children.length; i++) {
            var bg = children[i].currentStyle.backgroundImage;
            if(bg != 'none' && bg.toLowerCase().search(/\.png("|\')?\)$/) != -1) {
                DD_belatedPNG.fixPng(children[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! - I'm going to check next time I start a new project but this looks exactly like what I was after. It would be great to work out a non-jquery solution too - that way when a project is started you can just throw it in and forget about it. I've started doing this with domAssistant and Selectivizr, even if I'm using Jquery so don't actually need DomAssistant. THANKS again.

Comment: Thanks again for this. I've tested the jquery version and this works even with the "background" CSS property rather than having to reply on using "background-image".

As expected there is a definite delay using this over sticking each selector in. At a very unscientific count, on one computer running ie6 I found the default DD_belated way to kick in at 10 seconds and this at about 17. Obviously there are loads of things that would have an affect on this! - But in my tests as there is alreay a delay its worth at least trying this. THANKS!